# Assign a value to a variable in JSX for ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, jsx

```
{props.stories.map((story) =>
    <div key={story.id}>
        {story = story.story}
        <SliderItem story={story} />
    </div>
)}
```

The above code throws an error saying:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys

because `story` in line number 3 is an object.

I can move that condition directly as `<SliderItem story={story.story} />`, but I want to know if there is any way I can assign my calculated value to a variable and use it in JSX?

I want to apply some logic like:

```
{ let storyObj = story.type === 'story' && story.story ? story.story : story }
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Everything between `{}` in the JSX is just JavaScript, so you can do the following:

```
{props.stories.map((story) => {
  const storyObj = (story.type === 'story' && story.story) ? story.story : story;
  return (
    <div key={story.id}>
      <SliderItem story={storyObj} />
    </div>
  );
})}
```

Comment: I think the general desire here is to have a normal variable declaration inside jsx, when you don't have something like a .map call creating such an opportunity

Comment: @DevinGRhode - on the one hand, I agree. On the other hand, I see only two possibilities: a) you wish to create an expression based on existing JS variable(s), in which case there *is* a JS context that defined that variable. The only reason OP had trouble is they were using "short" form of `map`s return value, that lacked the explicit `{...}`. The fix was to convert to "long" form. b) You are defining a literal value, in which case any enclosing JS context works fine. BOTTOM LINE: "Add declaration to the tightest enclosing JS context" is always an available solution.

Comment: looks like very complicated and not straight forward.

Answer (score 12):

You can create a function outside the `render()` that will get correct value:

```
function getStory(storyObj) {
  return storyObj.type === 'story' && storyObj.story ? storyObj.story : storyObj;
}
```

And then use it in JSX:

```
{props.stories.map(storyObj =>
  <div key={storyObj.id}>
     <SliderItem story={getStory(storyObj)} />
  </div>
)}
```

Answer (score 7):

I think this would be a fairly elegant solution:

```js
function someReactFunctionalComponent(props) {
  const vars = {}

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>... lots of code ...</h1>
      {vars.someFoo_s = bar ? dance : undefined}
      <ul>
        {
          vars.someFoo=normalizeFoo(vars.someFoo_s),
          vars.someFoo_s.map((aFoo) => (
            <li>{aFoo}</li>
          ))
        }
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use an IIFE(Immediately Invoked Function Expression)

```
{props.stories.map((story) =>
    <div key={story.id}>
        {(() =>  {
          story = story.story
          return <SliderItem story={story} />
        })()}
    </div>
)}
```

Answer (score 3):

Though I wouldn't recommend it as it really obfuscates your code, you can use the comma operator to allow you to assign a value:

```
{story = story.story, <SliderItem story={story} />}
```

I'm not sure why you would want to do this however?

Comment: Note that this wouldn't allow you to create/declare a new variable. So things like the following will not work: `{let foo = 123, <Bar foo={foo} />}`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just pass in `story.story`??

```
  {props.stories.map((story) =>
    <div key={story.id}>
      <SliderItem story={story.story} fallback={story} />
    </div>
  )}
```

In your component if `this.props.story` is `undefined` then use `this.props.fallback`.

Comment: No.. My component should accept both structures. I don't want my end users to pass both props. I may not be the person who is using this component. And let's say `SliderItem` only accepts `story`